# TypeError: child_process_1.spawn is not a function

Tags: python, reactjs, electron, child-process

I'm using Electron + React JS as frontend which in turn will communicate the backend program(Python). I've looked for solutions and came up with something called python-shell library. This library helps to communicate or call out the backend.

**upload.js**

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(file)
    var pyShell  = require('python-shell');
    

    let options = {
        mode: 'text',
        args: [file]
    };
    
    pyShell.PythonShell.run('./py/backend.py', (err, results) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        
        console.log('results: ', results);
        results.textContent = results[0];
    });
    
}
```

**backend.py**

```
import sys
print('Hello from Python!')
sys.stdout.flush()
```

It shows me an error **TypeError: child_process_1.spawn is not a function**, and it shows the error location of index.ts(But there is no index.ts file in my entire directory).